# How webpagetest.org get first view time and visual progress?

Tags: javascript, web, html

How it can calculate the first view and progress? What's the definition?

I have tried puppeteer, but it's screenshot has frequency limitation.

first view
[image]

progress:
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Merijn dk Thank you for the reply. I want to make a tool to detect the first screen time and use it on the intranet. So I'd like to investigate the implementation of the relevant tools first

Comment: First screen time as in the time it takes to load the website without the cache being loaded already or?

Comment: @Merijndk Without the cache, and first meaningful screen already. Yesterday I have found the solution, use https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse to to find the first screen time, or use puppeteer to trace timeline, and analyze the json data by self(it has screenshots in base64). Thank u.